# ...is not a foreign key column and cannot be used here?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have two views in SQL, and have created mappings to them in Linq to SQL.

The two views have an association, which works fine, between Ticket.ProblemCode and Problem.Code

When I try to set UIHint("ForeignKey") on Ticket.ProblemCode and run the web page I get the error:

'ProblemCode' is not a foreign key column and cannot be used here.

Anyone know why?  More importantly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post on the ASP.NET forums:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1254559.aspx

Also, you said that you created the association in Linq to SQL.  Is there an actual PK/FK constraint in the database, or is it only represented in your dbml?

Comment: Ugh... the worst part is I tried that, but accidentally changed the ItemTemplate instead of the EditItemTemplate so I thought it didn't work...  Thanks!